# Format PowerShell time output

Tags: powershell, dos

I have a PowerShell script like this:

```
$owners = @{}
gwmi win32_process |% {$owners[$_.handle] = $_.getowner().user}
get-process | select processname,Id,StartTime,@{l="Owner";e={$owners[$_.id.tostring()]}}
```

I'd like to format the `StartTime` to appear as 24h format and dont show the seconds. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
$owners = @{}
gwmi win32_process |% {$owners[$_.handle] = $_.getowner().user}
get-process | select processname,Id,@{l="StartTime";e={ get-date $($_.starttime) -f "dd/MM/yy HH.mm" }},@{l="Owner";e={$owners[$_.id.tostring()]}}
```

Comment: Complementing a little @ruda here is the link with all the formatting options that can be used: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692801.aspx